# Delete/update strategy using unidirectional many-to-one with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a table FileUpdloaded in my system, that is used in several other tables. So ever uploaded file in my system is saved in that table (SqlServer FileStream)

So, every class that needs a uploaded file, I have a similar mapping :

```
m.ManyToOne(x => x.FileUploaded, map => {
                    map.Column("File");
                    map.Class(typeof(FileUploaded));
                    map.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
});
```

So, because its a unidirectional relation I am supposed to delete the file manually, right? 
I set the new file to the object and after that I explicity delete the old form the FileUploaded table:

```
var oldId = myObject.FileUploaded.Id;
myObject.FileUploaded = new FileUploaded(...)
session<FileUploaded>.Delete(oldId)
```

Is that the right way to do that? Or Am I messing up the mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `<many-to-one>` the only way to go is - as you've described. The documentation:

- [5.1.10. many-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

*(small cite)*

```
<many-to-one
        name="PropertyName"                                (1)
        column="column_name"                               (2)
        class="ClassName"                                  (3)
        cascade="all|none|save-update|delete"              (4)
        ...
```

> ... 
>   (4)   **cascade (optional)**: Specifies which operations should be cascaded from the parent object to the associated object.

So, there is no **all-delete-orphan**. And that means, that if we change reference of the `<many-to-one>` we cannot profit from orphan deletion. The only way is to delete explicitly and manually...